# Vertical ropdown menu with several submenus

Tags: menu, dropdown, submenu

I want to create vertical menu with dropdowns and several submenus.
I have code from codepen like I need but I am very far from JS and can't figure out how to add submenu.
here is codepen page:   bit.ly/2CagVLI  (please copy link, I can't insert clickable URL)

I want to turn this into menu like this

[image: Click for image]

Comment: To insert clickable url, please consult Links section in [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). But you better copy the relevant code rather than paste a link.

Comment: site says too many code in my post :(